# Is it possible to speed up iteration on large JSON file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, loops

I have 3 JSON files (provinces.json, cities.json, barangays.json).

There are 88 provinces listed in the JSON file. Each province has many cities and each city has many barangays.

The **provinces.json** has the following sample content: (provinces are around 88 records)

```
{
  'provCode': 01,
  'provName': 'Province Name'
}
```

The **cities.json** has the following sample content: (cities are around 1647 records)

```
{
  'ctyCode': 001,
  'ctyName': 'City Name',
  'provCode: 01
}
```

The **barangays.json** has the following sample content: (barangays are around 8197 records)

```
{
  'brgyCode': 0001,
  'brgyName': 'Barangay Name',
  'ctyCode': 001,
  'provCode: 01
}
```

I am using 1 dropdown select for each of the JSON files on which I trigger an `onchange` event to populate the next dropdown select.

The relevant code as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  populateProvince();

  $('#province').change(function() {
    populateCity();
  });

  $('#city').change(function() {
    populateBrgy();
  });

  function populateProvince() {
    $('#province').html('');
    $.getJSON('provinces.json', function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, object) {
        $('#province').append(`<option data-code="${object.provCode}" value="${object.provName.toUpperCase()}">${object.provName.toUpperCase()}</option>`);
      });
    });
  }

  function populateCity() {
    $('#city').html('');
    $.getJSON('cities.json', function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, object) {
        if(object.provCode === $('#province option:selected').data('code')) {
          $('#city').append(`<option data-code="${object.ctyCode}" value="${object.ctyName.toUpperCase()}">${object.ctyName.toUpperCase()}</option>`);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function populateBrgy() {
    $('#brgy').html('');
    $.getJSON('barangays.json', function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, object) {
        if(object.provCode === $('#province option:selected').data('code') && object.ctyCode === $('#city option:selected').data('code')) {
          $('#brgy').append(`<option data-code="${object.brgyCode}" value="${object.brgyName.toUpperCase()}">${object.brgyName.toUpperCase()}</option>`);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
</script>
<select id='province'></select>
<select id='city'></select>
<select id='brgy'></select>
```

Basically, what I do is. Upon loading the page, I populate the province select dropdown with `provinces.json` content.

Then upon selecting a province, I will iterate to the `cities.json` and check if it matches the `provCode` the if it matches the selected province it will populate the cities select dropdown.

Same with the barangay if it matches the selected province and city then it will populate the barangays select dropdown.

Populating provinces and cities are quite tolerable. But when I start iterating to the barangays with 8000+ records but only append around 20 records based on selected province and city the webpage stops like 10 seconds or more on an older machine and 5 seconds on newer machines.

The question is, is there an efficient way of doing this? How to speed up iterating large JSON files?

Comment: Why are you looking up the string on every iteration? `$('#province option:selected').data('code')` Code does not change, pull it outside of the loop. Read the values once, not every iteration.

Comment: Is there a need to ajax in the json more than once? does it change often enough to warrant pulling in a new one more than once per page load?

Comment: @epascarello Each province has a unique id. Each city belongs to one province. Each barangay has one city and has one province. I only need to populate city based on the selected province.

Comment: Considering you have to pull in all three entirely, wouldn't there be a performance benefit in combining them into one? That way you don't have to iterate through all of the cities, and instead can just grab the ones for the selected province. No filtering/iterating required, just reference by selected id.

Comment: @DavidAngulo yes, but it is not changing on every iteration.... Basically you loop through.... On each iteration you look for the DOM element, you than look for the data attribute, you grab the same value every time. You keep looking for the element every single time you look at an index in your JOSN.

Comment: As a note: In JSON only double quotes are valid for keys and values. So what you show here is not JSON.

Comment: `{ "pid1": { "name" : "pfoo1", "cities": { "cid1": { "name": "cfoo1", "barangays": { etc...}}` for example would allow you to pull only the relevant cities and only the relevant barangays per dropdown with zero iteration other than building the dropdowns themselves. Can also be done with arrays.

Comment: you need to cache `$('#province option:selected').data('code')` and all your other non-dynamic in-loop jquery code in a simple primitive variable just outside the loop/each, that will DRASTICALLY speed things up.

Comment: @KevinB I like the idea but I guess I am just too lazy to rewrite 10000+ records of JSON into that format. The current JSON file I am using is just a dump I found on the internet.

Comment: @DavidAngulo You don't need to manually rewrite the JSON records. A simple script could rewrite it for you.

Comment: yup, doing it in each page load up front would work, but it would also likely cause the same kind of delay, only in a less noticeable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like to load the json files only once so on every change you can avoid call over network

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let provs,cities,barangays;

  $.getJSON('provinces.json').done((json) =>{
    provs=json;
    populateProvince();// wait till you get data for province
  })
   $.getJSON('cities.json').done(function(json){
    cities =json;
  })
   $.getJSON('provinces.json').done(function(json){
    barangays =json;
  })


  $('#province').change(function() {
    populateCity();
  });

  $('#city').change(function() {
    populateBrgy();
  });

  function populateProvince(){
    //rest of the code
  }
  function populateCity() {
    //rest of the code
  }
  function populateBrgy(){
    //rest of the code
  }

})
```

Also don't append `option` to dom inside each iteration. Rather create a variable and append to it , then append that variable only once

```
function populateProvince(){
    $('#province').html('');
    let provOptions = ''
      $.each(data, function(index, object) {
        provOptions += $(`<option data-code="${object.provCode}" 
                                value="${object.provName.toUpperCase()}">
                                ${object.provName.toUpperCase()}
                                </option>`)

      });
      $('#province').append(provOptions)
  }
```

Comment: After using this it is indeed faster as it only loads the data once then stores it into the memory for further use. I guess the problem with my code lies in `append` method as the webpage hangs until appending is done.

Comment: Looks great. Thank you for the effort. In addition to your answer, I am considering the use of pure VanillaJS and dropping the jQuery in my code to make it faster.